# Using LIKE in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

The first section of code is what i used to create a size class report. It works beautifully. However, I need to narrow the focus of this operation but only on CODE values that begin with 11 or 21. Code is a character (6) primary key field, if that helps. The Where statement that I am trying to use is at the bottom. I put it right after the first SELECT statement. I get an incorrect syntax error.

Does it matter where I put the where statement?
Second, does the where statement seem correct for what it is intended for?

```
SELECT 
[Areas].[Area], 
[classSizes].[sizeclass],
SUM([data].[Employment]) AS [Employment in Size Class],
CASE COUNT([data].[Employment])
    WHEN 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE COUNT([data].[Employment])
    END  AS [Number of Sites]
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Area] 
FROM [sizeclassreport]) AS [Areas] 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT 
            [sizeclass] 
        FROM [sizeclassreport]) AS [classSizes]
 LEFT OUTER JOIN [sizeclassreport] [data]
 ON [Areas].[Area] = [data].[Area] 
    AND [classSizes].[sizeclass] = [data].[sizeclass]
GROUP BY
[areas].[Area], 
[classSizes].[sizeclass]
ORDER BY
[areas].[Area], 
[classSizes].[sizeclass]

Where code like '11%' or '21%'

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Where'
```

Comment: The Where must come immediately after the From clause

Comment: Of course the order of the syntax matters, just like any kind of development in any language. The documentation would show you this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql

Comment: the WHERE should be after all joins and before the group by

Comment: `WHERE` should be before the `GROUP BY`, and it needs to be `'11%'` rather than `'%11'`.

Comment: Learn the SQL syntax.  I'm surprised that you are able to write complex enough query, but don't know where to put WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what others have said about the order of the clauses, this is invalid syntax:

```
Where code like '11%' or '21%'
```

Instead you need to write:

```
Where code like '11%' or code like '21%'
```

Comment: He also need to encapsulate his cross join with a end bracket )

Comment: I don't mean to imply that this is the ONLY problem.   :)

Comment: Ok, took your suggestions and it works, so to speak. However, it returns no values which is not correct. Does "code" have to be included in the Group by and Order by clauses at the end?

Comment: No, but as one of the comments suggests, you may have the % sign in the wrong place.   To get codes that BEGIN with "11", you would do `LIKE '11%'` instead of `LIKE '%11'`